# How to create an alert if a change happens in one section of a decoupled code?

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the following code pieces A, B, C. A and B are class libraries while C is an executable file. B references A and also imports A. C references both A and B but imports only B and does not import A. I am deliberately including the word “imports” alongside “references” as I have a question on this point which is found in the later part of this document.

In A, a class `MathOperations` is defined which contains a function `ADD`. The code for A is given below and it was saved as `MyMathsLibrary.dll`.

```
Public Class MathOperations 'Part A
    Function ADD(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
        Return (a + b)
    End Function
End Class
```

The part B has a class `Factory` which hosts a function `createMathsObject` which returns an object of `MathOperations` type. B references A and also imports A.  The code for B is given below and was saved as `FactoryMathsLibrary.dll`.

```
Imports MyMathsLibrary 'Part B
Public Class Factory
    Shared Function createMathsObject() As MathOperations
        Return New MathOperations()
    End Function
End Class
```

Part C refers to B and A but imports only B, i.e. MathsLibrary.dll. The code for part C is given below:

```
Imports FactoryMathsLibrary 'Part C
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim a, b As Integer
        Dim m As Object = Factory.createMathsObject()
        Console.Write("Enter 1st value: ")
        a = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter 2nd value: ")
        b = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("a + b = {0}", m.ADD(a, b))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

**The problem I am facing in this setup:**
When I change the name of the `ADD` function in part A to say `addNumbers` and we do not change the name of `ADD` function in part C to `addNumbers`, my code is failing at run-time which is a big problem. Ideally if any change happens in the called code (here A and B), I would like to have that flagged in the calling code (here denoted by C) as a compile-time error. Can someone pls tell how to achieve that? This is my first question.

**My other question is as follows:**
As mentioned previously, part C references both A and B but imports only B. Ideally I want a completely de-coupled structure that is B references only A and C references only B. I had posted this question in SO and I was told that such a decoupled structure is not possible and that C must reference both A and B - not only B. However I ask this question again because I have come across a youtube video where the person is successfully implementing a completely decoupled structure in C#. Now I dont know C# - is it so that such a decoupled structure is allowed in C# and not in VB?? If anybody is curious then he may check approximately the first 15 minutes of the following video:

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4mCbaqH8zs&t=72s)

Comment: Firstly, you need to gain an understanding of what you're actually importing. You don't import a library. You import a namespace. The root namespace for a project is the same as the output assembly by default but it doesn't have to be. Importing a namespace is simply a convenience and has no effect on what types you can access. I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html).

Comment: As for your request, it's simply not possible. You are using late binding when you declare a variable of type `Object` and then access some member of a more specific type via that reference. Late binding requires the compiler to ignore the fact that the member you're accessing doesn't actually exist on the type of the reference you're accessing it on. If you expect the compiler to know what members the object will have at run time then you need to declare the variable as that type rather than `Object`. You can't have it both ways. Either the compiler knows about your type or it doesn't.

Comment: Note that the compiler doesn't even know that that type has an `Add` method in the first place, so how could it know that that method had changed? As you're using late binding, it is simply taking your word for the fact that that member will exist when it's needed. If it doesn't, that's your fault. You should avoid late binding wherever possible but sometimes it's required. In those situations, it's your responsibility to know what members are available and access them by the right names. You ought to read up on late and early binding.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for your time and your comments.

Comment: *C must reference both A and B* - If your factory is in B and the things it manufactures is in A, and C wants to use it to manufacture some x and then use x, then C needs a reference to A

Comment: @CaiusJard, that's only true if you want to use early binding. The code provided is using late binding, so no reference is required. It's just that, without the reference, there's no way for the compiler to know anything about the type in A when building C. I know you know this but, for the benefit of the OP, that's the whole difference between early and late binding, i.e. type-checking can be done early (at compile time) or late (at run time).

Comment: Argh, I wrote an answer to this but then lost it when the cellphone battery died and I haven't the time to write it again. Long story short, the first 15 minutes of the video do exactly the same in c# that you do here; use the `dynamic` keyword to achieve a late binding situation that explodes because method name is changed. It's resolved by using interfaces to promise what the set of methods are available on the object that is returned from the factory. vB has interfaces too; you can do the same in VB as they did in C#, and you can drop the `As Object` and make it `As ISomeInterface`

Comment: The factory project references the interface, the implementing project references it, the using project references it so they all know what an ICalculator is and that it has an Add() method, and the factory is free to choose to return a HungOverCalculator (that has a thread sleep 3000 in every operation) on Monday, and a RegularCalculator the rest of the time; both calculators have an Add, because the interface promises that they do and the compiler checks.. there isn't really any magic there, and I don't really regard it as "fully decoupled" because everything references the interface

Comment: definition and if that changed everything would fall apart anyway, or if the implementations were changed so they no longer implemented the interface then everything would fall apart again.. Project A already has an interface (contract) that you don't use by late binding it. Separating it into interface and implementation could be useful if you see some valid, varied reason for doing so (such as being able to swap in pretend objects that always act in a certain way for testing purposes) but jmc's original point stands; you either late bind or early bind - interfaces don't let you do both

Comment: @CaiusJard many thanks for all these points. Let me take some time and assimilate them.  I am at beginner level so lots of inputs for me to process.

Comment: @CaiusJard First Part: My question is w.r.t to you statement "C must reference both A and B - If your factory is in B and the things it manufactures is in A, and C wants to use it to manufacture some x and then use x, then C needs a reference to A". Also, I request that you please please have another look at the video between 7 to 18 minutes. There seems to be a contradiction between your statement and what is being shown here.

Comment: @CaiusJard Next Part: In the video the teacher has three components to his project: UI (part C); Factory (part B) and MathsComponent (part A). The alphabets represent the corresponding parts in my question above. In the mentioned duration the teacher clearly says that the UI references Factory and the Factory references MathsComponent. The UI (i.e. C) does not reference the MathsComponent (i.e. A) – the person actually deletes C’s reference to A around time = 13 minutes. But everything still works!!

Comment: @CaiusJard Last Part: My question is : Do you think that C actually references A but may be the communication is unclear in the video. Or is it that this structure i.e. C not referencing A is allowed in C#? I have zero knowledge of C# and hence asking.

Comment: No contradiction, I was talking about the situation where you have the compiler checking that everything is wired up correctly, but the video at 13-18 minutes uses `dynamic`, which isn't "compiler checks it is wired up", it is "developer knows what theyre doing and all the calls they make are correct, compiler doesn't verify that Add method exists; if it doesnt, runtime will explode" - which it does explode

Comment: All in, we're still only going back to jmc's point; you either have the compiler check your method calls or you don't. If the compiler doesn't check, the runtime will, and your program will crash if you got it wrong. The reason we have the compiler check is because you, the dev, still have control while you're compiling.. By the time the runtime is hitting a mistake of you using the wrong method name it's too late to fix; the product is shipped and angry customers are on the phone..

Comment: At 13 minutes the reference to MathsComponent is deleted and you instantly see the using statement in the background ge a red wiggly line. That statement will end up removed, UI will reference Factory, Factory references MathsComponent and Factory is declared to return dynamic which means it will return *something* (it returns a mathswhatever) and UI can use it, so long as it doesn't make any mistakes in the usage (spell methods correctly etc) because the compiler is no longer checking that part. If this is "decoupled" in your eyes then great; you got there. VB can do it just like C#

Comment: It's fragile though, as you can see in later minutes. Eventually an interface project D is created.. Everything references D and D controls what the types look like externally but only A controls how they're implemented internally and only B controls which A (there could be many) implementation is handed out. C just uses whatever looks-like-D-but-really-its-a-variation-on-A it is given by B. It doesn't care about the implementation, and the idea is that whatever the guts, externally it behaves the same.

Comment: @CaiusJard Firstly my apologies for replying late. Also, thank you for commenting in so much detail. I completely understand jmc’s point in which has clarified beyond doubt that the either the compiler checks the method calls or they are checked at run-time. Just to be sure that I understand your statement clearly, I am rephrasing in my words what you had explained – I request you to confirm if my understanding is correct.

Comment: @CaiusJard In the video, time = 14 minutes 23 seconds, a DYNAMIC function named CreateMaths() is created in the FACTORY layer. Although this function returns an object of a specific type, namely MathsLibrary type, it is still a case of late binding because the function itself is DYNAMIC - compiler does not check the method calls. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @CaiusJard Also, such a late binding structure allows the UI to reference the FACTORY only and the does not need to reference the MathsComponent – Is this observation correct? ---Asking because the does not fail at run-time initially that is time = 17min 24 sec. In fact I changed `Shared Function createMathsObject() As MathOperations` in part B of my project to `Shared Function createMathsObject() As Object` and I see that in the code given above the part C does not need to reference part A, the compilation works well.

Comment: @CaiusJard So my takeaway from your comments is that the if part B returns an object type we are not needing part A to reference part C as the compiler is not checking the method calls. Could u pls tell if I am on the right track?

Comment: @jmcilhinney many thanks for clarifying in simple words the late binding concept. Also the link you gave is helpful...so thank you for that also.

Comment: Your understanding of `dynamic` is correct; the compiler won't check the presence/absence of the methods at compile time. This is risky; either the dev got it right and nothing explodes at runtime or they got it wrong..

Comment: You've switched to talking about object, which in c# terms is slightly different. If you're talking about Object in VB, then i understand- making things Object (or simply "not saying" what they are) and having late binding turned on is the vb equivalent of c# dynamic. object itself doesn't necessarily mean late-bind though; it's merely the parent of everything else. in the OO languages that are c# and vb effectively everything is an object, and a variable of type object can hold anything, including functions. This means you can sure declare a func to return object and send back anything..

Comment: ..and in intellisense it will look pretty sparse; you'll struggle to tell what it is even, because it'll just have a couple of methods, but that's not late binding; the compiler *knows* your thing is an object and you''l have to cast it to do anything reasnable with it, at which point the compiler will believe you when you declare it to be an X by the cast and let you try to call X's methods on it. It's not late binding because youre still engaged in some process of proving to the *compiler* that you know what the object is. With late binding the compiler stops caring to check on you

Comment: All in, nothing in that video is impossible in VB, it's just that the bit of the video you seem so captivated by/drawn to and want to do in VB is the same part I'm sitting here and saying "mmm.. don't do it; it's throwing away one of the most useful features of .net and for nothing.. If you want to code that kind of nasty, take up javascript :D"

Comment: @CaiusJard Shall keep the advice in your last comment in mind.